# Show last record for current User(ID) where ID is in 2 seperate fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to write a little Messagecenter for my Project.

The problem I'm running into is that I only want to show the very last message from or to user, the one which came last will be shown.

The Table has a ID a Sender_ID, Receiver_ID and a MessageTXT.

Until now I have used:

```
@messages = Message.find_by_sql("select * from messages where id IN(SELECT MAX( id ) FROM messages WHERE sender_id = #{current_user.id} OR receiver_id = #{current_user.id} GROUP BY sender_id, receiver_id )")
```

Which gives me the last message to and the last message from a different user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a named `scope` and not have to use `find_by_sql` which is really a last-resort tool.

Example:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_user, lambda { |user_id|
    where([ 'sender_id=? OR receiver_id=?', user_id, user_id)
  }
end
```

Using this you can retrieve the last one:

```
@last_message = Message.for_user(user_id).order('id DESC').first
```

That should generate a query similar to what you have defined.

Comment: I only want to see the last message from or to a user. So if i send the last Message i see my post. If the other User wrote back i see his Message.

Comment: This should do it, since it looks for messages either sent `OR` received by a given user. Ordering by descending ID should pick out the most recent one as well if IDs are issued sequentially.

Comment: If you want to do this for all users, it's possible to write a different scope, but your example specifically targets `current_user`.

Comment: Yeah you where right. Scops did solve my problem! `last_msg_for_user = Message.for_user(current_user, u).order('id DESC').first
      @messages << last_msg_for_user if last_msg_for_user`

Comment: here is my scope `scope :for_user, lambda { |curr, u|
    where( '(sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?) OR (receiver_id=? AND sender_id=?)', curr.id, u.id, curr.id, u.id)
  }`

Comment: @tadman , this is the most beautiful, accurate answer I've ever read so far, for a question as (fairly) complex as this! Thank you (y)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your query is that you forgot to specify the order and you forgot to specify "LIMIT 1".   You should look at tadman's answer for a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Message.where("sender_id = :user_id OR receiver_id = :user_id", {:user_id => current_user.id}).order('created_at').last
```

This should create an SQL request that lists all the messages where your user is sender or receiver, sorts them by creation date, and gives you the last one.

I've sorted the messages with their creation date instead of the id, because the DB may not use auto-increment ids. Consider adding an index on the `created_at` column to increase efficiency.

Also avoid using "#{...}" in SQL request, special characters may not be crrectly handled, and it's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
@messages = Message.find_by_sql("select * from messages 
      WHERE sender_id = #{current_user.id} OR receiver_id = #{current_user.id}")
```

or you need not use `find_by_sql`, you can do it as

```
@messages = Message.find(:all, :conditions => ["sender_id = ? or
                          receiver_id = ?", current_user.id, current_user.id]);
```

this will return array of matching condition ordered by id by default.remember that the id is auto created and incremented so the last message will have highest id so you can get the last message as below

```
@last_message = @messages.last
```